# Subdivison proxy preview?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

dear Blender community. Is there a way to preview subdivided model without actually adding subd modifier? For example: press a hotkey and get a preview of the model with subdivision levels added.
(Just like Dynamic SubD in Zbrush, or Smooth Proxy preview in Maya).

Comment: In object mode with the mesh selected just ctrl + n where n is the number of subdivisions you want. Yes it auto adds the modifier but its a quick way to preview. Then ctrl + 0 to turn it off. This means it still has the modifier but set to 0 in the viewport. Seems a quick way to preview?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful solution! (still gotta adapt it to industry-compatible keymap) Is it possible to make subdiving back and forth with Ctrl+ Mousewheel Up or Down (correspondingly)?